# Using a MCP23017 for detecting open door/window

Tags: switches, cables, pullup

I'm not a hardware guy. My plan is to read input states using an MCP23017 connected to a Raspberry PI.

My doubt is about the switching circuit. My plan is to use Ethernet cable pairs to wire the MCP23017 pins to magnetic door and window switches.

I might have up to 20 meters of cable between the switch and the MCP23017 pin (20+20 ohm resistance). I'm planning to use a shielded Ethernet cable.

Are 10k pull-up resistors enough to have a reliable and noise free switch detection circuit? 
Should I place any other component next to MCP23017 pins to ensure a reliable switch status read? 
Any advice on which Ethernet cable class is best?

**UPDATE:**
In the meanwhile I found this very interesting article: https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/apr/protecting-inputs-in-digital-electronics

I like the R-C idea (fig.8).

I also have to consider that in my case switches are most the time closed to ground and I have to detect open condition. Does this last point matter on the design? 
I'm using 3.3V to power the MCP, what would be the right R & C values?

Comment: Are you planning on using differential transceivers?

Comment: This is the kind of thing standard intruder alarms do with ease using cheap 4 or 6 core cable, so there's no need to go to the expense of shielded twisted pairs. 10k should be fine as a pullup but you should probably add something like a 10uF capacitor to ground to filter out any noise.

Comment: What is a "differential transceivers" for?

Comment: I spent some time in googling "ceramic vs electrolytic caps", so now I'm more confused than before **:)**  I was thinking I better use a ceramic cap for this app, but then I saw how expensive a ceramic 10uF cap is and I changed my mind in using an electrolytic one. Am I right?